# How does principle of relativity imply constant velocity of propagation of interaction?

Tags: special-relativity

In the introduction of the book '*The classical theory of fields*' by Landau & Lifshitz, it is told that '*From the principle of relativity it follows in particular that the velocity of propagation of interactions is the same in all inertial frames*'. i.e. the velocity of propagation of interactions (signal velocity) is a universal constant.

The principle of relativity states that the laws of physics should remain the same in any inertial frame. How can a modified signal velocity bring about a change in the laws of physics, or how does it enable an observer to know if he is moving not? How does the principle of relativity imply constant signal velocity?

Comment: Could you explain a bit how did you combine the two assumptions and arrive at *velocity of propagation of interaction is the same in all frames*?

Comment: So, the velocity of signal itself is a law of physics?

Comment: have you solved your question? Because i have the same on

Answer (score 2):

Given that we assume this maximum signal velocity is finite, if it were not constant between inertial frames then one could boost into an inertial frame in which the signal velocity is zero. Then, in this frame there is no interaction whereas in other frames there are interactions, which is a difference in the laws of physics.

Comment: that is not true because the body will move in the direction where the interaction comes from